# Which would mount faster initrd or initramfs ?

Tags: initramfs, initrd

I want to boot my linux as fast as possible.

I have to make a choice between initrd and intiramfs.

Which one should mount faster and have smaller size?

Answer (score 4):

For as fast as possible boot, you will probably want to boot without any initrd/initramfs (which is totally possible). You'll have to make sure that all drivers that are necessary to get access to main fs (like filesystem or HDD controller) are compiled into kernel not as modules.